# Wifi Slow when connected to bluetooth on 18.04 Ubuntu

Tags: networking, bluetooth, atheros

My wifi speed significantly drops when i connect to bluetooth speaker.
I came across many posts but as I am new to Ubuntu I am not able to figure out commands and their errors like as I tried following

```
sudo options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

but it gives me error

```
sudo: options: command not found
```

Can someone please give me steps to solve the problem also ?
Thanks in advance

Update 1: added following

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

to `nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
With no luck, Also one more behaviour i noticed is that. When I connect bluetooth my wifi begins to ask authentication again and again. i am using Asus laptop.

Update 2: `grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/*`
For this command : `No such file or directory`

Update 3: Output of`lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 54:27:1e:58:4e:9d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f787ffff memory:f7880000-f788ffff
```

Comment: The command should be `echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: tried with no luck :( even restarted also after making changes

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `grep [[:alnum:]] /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/*`

Comment: I believe the parameter bt_coex_active=0 should be Y or N. Y is the default. Please try =N.

Comment: @chili555 Putting =N also dint solve my problem :(

Comment: @Jeremy31 updated the question.

Comment: I am sorry what is the deal about logical name of wifi, when i disconnect to bluetooth wifi speed restores to 30 Mbps with bluetooth connected it is <1Mbps.

Comment: Ummm NO, results are still the same, Now i have pasted this `options wlp3s0 bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8`  by using this command `nano /etc/modprobe.d/wlp3s0.conf
`

Comment: @Kulfy In fact, options are applied to the driver name, in this case *iwlwifi* and not the interface. Please see:`modinfo iwlwifi | grep parm`

Comment: Shall I show output of `modinfo iwlwifi | grep parm` will that be of any benefit to you guys ?

Comment: That's a complicated question, @Kulfy Please set up a chat and we'll discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

The driver *iwlwifi* is a driver for Intel wireless devices. Your driver is ath9k and is for Atheros devices.

First, let’s do some cleanup. We’ll remove the ineffective parameter:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/wlp3s0.conf
```

The change you made to iwlwifi.conf will be ignored since the driver isn’t used.

Next, try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1 bt_ant_diversity=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1746164

Also, please note that bluetooth operates at 2.45 GHz; very close to channel 9 in wifi. It may be helpful to set your router to a fixed channel, not auto-select, and as far away as possible, channel 1, to see if it helps.

Comment: No it is still same :(

Comment: Can i have possibility to change the driver? can that solve the problem ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to slightly change the 'echo'. Please try the revised solution.

Comment: Nops, still same.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is to try a live session of Ubuntu 18.10 to see if the driver in kernel 4.18.0-xx is an improvement.

Comment: I tried that too, but still same.

Comment: Would this approach work with the `ath10k` driver?